# Issue with Jest during the unit tests - getContext() is not implemented

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, html5-canvas, jsdom

When I ran my unit tests I found that I get the following error:

```
Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext 
(without installing the canvas npm package)
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue first its necessary to install [jest-canvas-mock](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-canvas-mock) you can use yarn or npm.

```
yarn add -D jest-canvas-mock
```

And then add this into your *`jest.config.js`* or the jest configuration section inside the *`package.json`*.

```
setupFiles: [
    'jest-canvas-mock',
    '<rootDir>/config/jest/setupFiles'
  ]
```

Comment: There's a few questions on Stack Overflow that are answered by "just install jest-canvas-mock and here's how to do 'setupFiles'".

It'd be really helpful if those answers included a complete example test... just a trivial test would be fine but showing *how* jest-canvas-mock is used.

Answer (score 0):

the [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61357439/15855290) for this question helped me to fix the issue with minimum knowledge. i write this answer how I resolve the issue using the official doc [DOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-canvas-mock)

`Package.json` that I have is as follows

```
 "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit --watch",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
```

under the projects folder, I have another folder named tests where I write end2end test and unit test. on that test folder, i created a file name `setup.js` where I import necessary modules as follows

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify";
import axios from "axios";
import globalVariables from "../src/helper/globalVariables";
import globalFunctions from "../src/helper/globalFunctions";
Vue.use(Vuetify);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
Vue.prototype.$gv = globalVariables;
Vue.prototype.$gf = globalFunctions;
```

under my project folder, I have a file named `jest.config.js` where I set up the `setup.js` file to test the units. the file `jest.config.js` possesses the following codes

```
module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
  verbose: true,
  reporters: [
    "default",
    [
      "./node_modules/jest-html-reporter",
      {
        pageTitle: "VGC Unit Test",
      },
    ],
  ],
  setupFiles: ["jest-canvas-mock", "./tests/setup.js"],
};
```

include the below line of the code inside your `jest.config.js` and define the path of your `setup.js` file

```
setupFiles: ["jest-canvas-mock", "./tests/setup.js"]
```

this will solve the issue `Error: Not implemented: HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext  (without installing the canvas npm package)`

Answer (score 0):

If you only get one function error for HTMLCanvasElement, you can simply mock that function when setting up jest:

In setup file as mentioned in above answers, mock the function showing error:

```
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext = () => {};
```